# p:dashboard keep sort order after close

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I want to use this primefaces dashboard 
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/dashboard.xhtml

dashboard.xhtml

```
<div style="height:500px">
    <h:form>
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />

        <p:dashboard id="board" model="#{dashboardView.model}">
            <p:ajax event="reorder" listener="#{dashboardView.handleReorder}" update="msgs" />

            <p:panel id="sports" header="Sports">
                <h:outputText value="Sports Content" />
            </p:panel>

            <p:panel id="finance" header="Finance">
                <h:outputText value="Finance Content" />
            </p:panel>

            <p:panel id="lifestyle" header="Lifestyle">
                <h:outputText value="Lifestyle Content"  />
            </p:panel>

            <p:panel id="weather" header="Weather">
                <h:outputText value="Weather Content" />
            </p:panel>

            <p:panel id="politics" header="Politics">
                <h:outputText value="Politics Content" />
            </p:panel>
        </p:dashboard>

        <div style="clear:both" />
    </h:form>
</div>
```

DashBoardView.java

```
package org.primefaces.showcase.view.panel;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.event.CloseEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.DashboardReorderEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.ToggleEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.DashboardColumn;
import org.primefaces.model.DashboardModel;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultDashboardColumn;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultDashboardModel;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DashboardView implements Serializable {

    private DashboardModel model;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        model = new DefaultDashboardModel();
        DashboardColumn column1 = new DefaultDashboardColumn();
        DashboardColumn column2 = new DefaultDashboardColumn();
        DashboardColumn column3 = new DefaultDashboardColumn();

        column1.addWidget("sports");
        column1.addWidget("finance");

        column2.addWidget("lifestyle");
        column2.addWidget("weather");

        column3.addWidget("politics");

        model.addColumn(column1);
        model.addColumn(column2);
        model.addColumn(column3);
    }

    public void handleReorder(DashboardReorderEvent event) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();
        message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
        message.setSummary("Reordered: " + event.getWidgetId());
        message.setDetail("Item index: " + event.getItemIndex() + ", Column index: " + event.getColumnIndex() + ", Sender index: " + event.getSenderColumnIndex());

        addMessage(message);
    }

    public void handleClose(CloseEvent event) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Panel Closed", "Closed panel id:'" + event.getComponent().getId() + "'");

        addMessage(message);
    }

    public void handleToggle(ToggleEvent event) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, event.getComponent().getId() + " toggled", "Status:" + event.getVisibility().name());

        addMessage(message);
    }

    private void addMessage(FacesMessage message) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }

    public DashboardModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }
}
```

[image]

It is very cool feature.

I make some drag&drop

[image]

and close tab of browser and open it again then all come to default.

[image]

I need somehow to keep this order.

Probably use cookies somehow or any other way. Is it possible and if yes how to do it?

**Important is that the widget's order should be saved for every user. By this I mean one of two options**:

1. every logged user can see this order in every devices
2. Without logging in browser but when open new browser the order should be by default. Or some other user open that order should be by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure not the best solution but a solution:

I guess I would save the events from handleReorder(DashboardReorderEvent event) in a database or in a file. And load the order in the postconstruct init. What do you think?

Edit like wrote in the comment it is not possible to serialize the event for me.

My second try is like this:

```
public void handleReorder(DashboardReorderEvent event) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();
        message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
        message.setSummary("Reordered: " + event.getWidgetId());
        message.setDetail("Item index: " + event.getItemIndex() + ", Column index: " + event.getColumnIndex() + ", Sender index: " + event.getSenderColumnIndex());

        addMessage(message);

        serializeEvent(event);
    }
```

The serializeEvent method does not serialize the event because this failed to me, but it serialize an Object with necessary informations.

```
private void serializeEvent(DashboardReorderEvent event) {
        String userName = userBean.getUserName();
        StackoverflowObject e = new StackoverflowObject(event);
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut =
            new FileOutputStream("c:/tmp/events"+userName+".txt");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(e);
            //out.writeObject(event.getWidgetId()+";"+  event.getItemIndex()+";"+ event.getColumnIndex());
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();

         } catch (Exception i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
```

in the postconstruct init you read the serialized object and decide where to put the widget. This will show you the idea (it is nearly 1 a.m. so I show you just the beginning)

```
@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        model = new DefaultDashboardModel();
        DashboardColumn column1 = new DefaultDashboardColumn();
        DashboardColumn column2 = new DefaultDashboardColumn();
        DashboardColumn column3 = new DefaultDashboardColumn();
        StackoverflowObject e =   deserializeEvent("politics");

        if (e != null &&"politics".equalsIgnoreCase(e.getWidgetId()) && e.getColumnId() == 0){
            column1.addWidget("politics");
        } else   if (e != null &&"politics".equalsIgnoreCase(e.getWidgetId()) && e.getColumnId() == 1){
            column2.addWidget("politics");
        }
        else{
            column3.addWidget("politics");
        }
```

.. do the same for all other widget

Now you have also the question to do it per user. The method deserializeEvent determinate the user and read the correct file for this user.

If you ask yourself how to get the user. In most cases like this

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser()
```

If you have a loginbean like in my example you can get it from your userBean.

Edit the stackoverflowObject looks like this

```
public class StackoverflowObject implements Serializable{


/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4921468076398836905L;
private String widgetId;
private int columnId;
private int itenId;
public StackoverflowObject(DashboardReorderEvent event) {
    this.setWidgetId(event.getWidgetId());
    this.setColumnId(event.getColumnIndex());
    this.setItenId(event.getItemIndex());
}
```

// +getter and setter

Comment: Why would this 'for sure' not be the best solution?

Comment: Good Idea. Can you please provide an example code for saving in file?

Comment: Important is that for every user should be saving order.

Comment: I can write you an code example but I guess I can do it this evening (so you have to wait until tonight, at the moment I am at work). I will also take make it for every user.

Comment: Important is save order for every user/browser/session. How can I write it to the file for every device?

Comment: I have problems with serializing the DashboardReorderEvent. Sorry but I promise tomorrow I will deliver

Comment: Hey Alex. I tried it a second time but I am not able to serialize the event. So save the event into a file or database failed. My second attempt is to save just the column and item Ids and reproduce what the user did

Comment: Please check the answer posting beucase I edited it.

Comment: No feedback ? No +1 ?

Comment: Sorry for long delay. I had a deadline. Right now I'm currently working on this. How can I deserialize concrete event from file? When I serialize one event after another the second one erase previous. I think better solutions is to save it to some Java Object that stores all info about order of widgets. And then serialize that Object.

Comment: I think it needs to save DashboardModel object. Serialize it and deserilize it.

Comment: No, why do you think that? Read  the data from the events, save that. Way safer than serializing. If something changes in the PF model, it breaks...

Comment: @Kukeltje What do you mean "save that"? Serialize event? What should I save in file?

Comment: Before 'save that' I wrote:  "read the data from the events"... This can all be seen in the showcase...

Comment: @pwain: Sorry, I downvoted... You should **not** save serialized events.... Storing (persistently) serialized java objects is bad practice. If something changes in the Dashboard events in PrimeFaces things fail....

Comment: Oh, wait... I only know see that the DashBoardEvent is not stored, but read and stored in a custom object. That is less dangerous since it is under your control. But I'd still store in in a more readable way (xml/json) (@pwain, downvote removed)

Comment: @Kukeltje could we continue discussion in primefaces forum https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=53253?